# Replace values with a "translation" from another table

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, subset, extract

So I am relatively new to R and I am having the following problem, for which I did not find an answer yet.

I have two tables, one of the sort

| ID | German |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hallo |
| 3 | Katze |
| 4 | Hund |

and another one with the English translation in it.

| English | German |
| --- | --- |
| hello | Hallo |
| cat | Katze |
| dog | Hund |

What I'd like to do is to replace the German words in the first table with the English terms from the second table. How do I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
> merge(df1,df2)[-1]
  ID English
1  1   hello
2  4     dog
3  3     cat
```

or `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df1)[setDT(df2),on = .(German)][,German:=NULL][]
   ID English
1:  1   hello
2:  3     cat
3:  4     dog
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 4L), German = c("Hallo", "Katze",
"Hund")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(English = c("hello", "cat", "dog"), German = c("Hallo",
"Katze", "Hund")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `match` from `base R`

```
df1$English <-  with(df1, df2$English[match(German, df2$German)])
df1[c("ID", "English")]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 4L), German = c("Hallo", "Katze",
 "Hund")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
 
df2 <- structure(list(English = c("hello", "cat", "dog"), German = c("Hallo",
 "Katze", "Hund")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ))
```